# List Malfunction? (Python)

Tags: python, list, artificial-intelligence

I'm having problems with my lists.
Obviously, I have just missed something. :P

Can someone tell me what is going wrong here and how to fix it?
Here is where I am having the malfunction:

```python
        On = [0, 0, [[0, 0],[0,1]]]
        tempList = []
        tempList.append(On[2])
        print(tempList)
        tempList.append([On[0],On[1]+1])
        print(tempList)
```

Just in case this is important, it is for my AI pathfinding.

The First Print:

`[[[[0, 0]], [0, 1]]]`

I wanted:

`[[0,0],[0,1]]`

The Second Print:

`[[[[0, 0]], [0, 1]], [0, 2]]`

I wanted:

`[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]]`

`On[2]` is supposed to track my past movements.
I was trying to get my past movements (`On[2]`) to combine with the current movement.

I want the `tempList` to be like this:
`[[0,1],[0,2],[0,3]]`

But instead I get this:
`[[[0,1],[0,2]],[0,3]]`

`On` is stored in this format(Or supposed to be): `[CurrentX,CurrentY,[[Step1X,Step1Y],[Step2X,Step2Y]]` etc.

If you need any more info, just tell me what you need.

EDIT: The problem is whith the `On` and the `tempList`.

EDIT2: If you people need to, I can post all of the code so you can run it. :/

Comment: Please fix the indentation.  An expression like `Nodes[''+(str(On[0]))+','+(str(On[1]+1))+''][0]` is almost totally unreadable.  Plus we don't know if Bottom is empty at the top of the script you've given, or what On or Nodes are.

Comment: @PaulCornelius
Yes, bottom is empty.
That part you wanted me to indent is not the problem.
It is around the `tempList` area.

Comment: FYI, StackOverflow "code snippets" are only for code that can be run by a web browser (JavaScript/CSS/HTML). They're not intended for other languages like Python.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy
Then how does everyone alse put large amounts of code in?

Comment: @user3339168, with a "code sample", like what I just edited your question to use. It's the `{}` editor widget.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy
K. Thanks. So... You don't know what's wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or http://sscce.org/ for guidance on writing sample code that helps people solve your problems effectively. I'm only going to spend the effort to determine whether I can tell what's wrong if you've spent the effort to make it easy for me to do so.

Comment: Thanks -- this still isn't complete enough to be runnable, but it's much better than it was. You get that in `tempList`, or you get that appended to `Bottom`? Perhaps instead of `Bottom.append(tempList)` you want `Bottom += tempList`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy
Like I said in the question, the problem is that somehow, the way I'm putting part of `On` together with `tempList` is causing that weird problem with the list.

Comment: Well, what I showed you in my comment above is an alternate way of "putting [them] together". :)

Comment: ...btw, note how in my answer, I'm defining all my variables, so folks can copy-and-paste my answers and run them in their own interpreter? Trying to make a question copy-and-paste ready helps too.

Comment: "The First Print" and "The Second Print" is worthless -- we don't know what they're printing! If you said `On=[[[[0, 0]], [0, 1]]]` was the correct starting value of `On`, before the sample code ran, and `[[[[0, 0]], [0, 1]], [0, 2]]` was the actual value of `tempList` after the code you gave ran, and some other specific thing was the *expected* value, then **that** would be useful. Again, read http://sscce.org/; I don't have time to continue handholding through trying to get this question into an answerable state.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy
The prints are printing `tempList`.
I'll add the expected value.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy
There, I made the code so that you could run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

> ```
> tempList.append([On[0],On[1]+1])
> ```

appends a list to the list. You want this:

```
tempList.extend([On[0], On[1] + 1])
```

Comment: Very improbable. There's no way I can think of that `.append()` and `.extend()` will ever have exactly the same result as each other.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Only if the argument is a single-character string.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy
I can give you an image as proof! I know you hate those! :P
Or you can read my second edit.

Comment: @user3339168, rather than "all your code", I'd rather "just enough code". For instance, if you gave a value of `On` as it's set immediately before the operation that misbehaves, the code for that misbehaving operation, the value you expect, and the value you get, that would be enough.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy
The error is at the core of the code. The whole program revolves around it. :/ (And edits it.)

Comment: Sure, but you can put a `print` right before the code, and another right after it, to isolate the place where the right value goes in and the wrong value comes out. If you can't break out a language- or toolchain-level problem from the rest of your code, you don't understand your issue well enough to be asking about it yet.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy
Do you just want me to make an attached file with the program in it, and you can fix it for me? (And tell me how of course.)

Comment: If the change in my answer doesn't fix it then the problem isn't in the code you've posted.

Comment: It looks like the OP changed _two_ `append`s to `extend`s, as opposed to only the one that needed to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
On = [0, 1, [[0, 0],[0,1]]]
tempList = []
tempList.extend(On[2])
print(tempList)
tempList.append([On[0],On[1]+1]) # changing only this line
print(tempList)
```

...yields...

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]]
```

...which is the stated desired result.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I miss typed what on equals.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Bottom` comes out as...

```
[0, 0, [[[0,1],[0,2],[0,3]]]]
```

...when you want it to be...

```
[0, 0, [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3]]]
```

...then the problem may not be with `tempList` and its construction at all, but with the `append` call, which appends its argument as a single element.

---

That is to say:

```
a=[1,2]
b=[3]
a.append(b)
```

...results in...

```
a == [1,2,[3]]
```

...rather than...

```
a == [1,2,3]
```

...which I'm presuming is what you actually want.

---

For that result, use either

```
a += b
```

or

```
a.extend(b)
```

Comment: I'm getting this now... `[[[0, 0]], 0, 5]`